# Symbology for Unique Values with Domain

Tags: arcgis-10.0, symbology, domains

I'm wondering if there is a workaround to this.

I want to symbolize a feature class categorically by unique values.  The field that I'm doing this on has about 5 unique values.  I also have a coded value domain on this field with about 3000 values.  When I try and symbolize the field, it creates a symbol for every value in the domain, not just for the values in the feature class.

Is there something I'm missing that will limit the symbology to only the unique values that are in the feature class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround at 10.0 (which could also be used at 10.1) is to use Add Values to add just the five that you want instead of using Add All Values.

At both versions you could use the Summary Statistics tool to find the unique values and get them in a table.

If you use 10.1 you should (I have not tested) be able to automate the process using the **[UniqueValuesSymbology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000005s000000)** class.

Comment: Right!  I always forget about the Summary Statistics tool, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the Summary Statistics tool to search for unique values and obtain them in a table.
2. Use Join data with the feature class and the table with unique values, use the keep only records option.
   3 Use simbology unique values, should show only the values that have data.
3. Copy the feature class and to this remove the join
   5 With is FC (without join) select unique value in symbology and use the option to import, select the FC that has join with the symbology with filters and go!!.